# Expect script doesn't execute properly through PHP

Tags: php, shell, expect

**Environment**

Centos 6.7

Plesk 12

Apache 2.2.15

PHP 5.4

The expect script is:

```
exp_internal 1
spawn /bin/su root
expect "Password: " 
send "supersecretthing\n" 
expect "$"
send "service iptables start\n"
expect eof
exit
```

I don't have the *#!* syntax because I execute the script via `expect /absoluteRoute/MyScript`.

When I call the `expect /absoluteRoute/MyScript` via Shell , it's cool. It does as it's supposed to do. But if I try the following via a Web Browser:

```
<?php
   echo exec ('/usr/bin/expect /absoluteRoute/MyScript');
?>
```

The PHP code ends up displaying this:

```
spawn /bin/su root
```

I've read other questions, I've created the **/var/www/.ssh** folder option, but nothing.

I would like to understand why I can't execute the expect script via PHP. Yes, the script has the appropriate permissions and ownership.

Comment: what do you expect to see?

Answer (score 0):

I think possible the problem is due to the `expect` script. Change it like this

```
spawn su root
expect "Password: "
send "pwd\r"
expect "\\\$"; # Matching literal dollar sign
send "service iptables start\r"
expect "\\\$"; # Matching prompt again.
# After sending 'exit' only, we can expect 'eof'
send "exit\r"
expect eof
```

I have tested this script and it is executed fine via `php`.

**Note :**

Alternatively, to match some common known prompt, you can define a variable like

```
set prompt "#|>|%|\\\$ $"; # We escaped the `$` symbol with backslash to match literal '$'
```

The last dollar sign represents line-end.

While the expect is used, we have to accompany with -re flag to specify that as a regular expression.

```
expect -re $prompt
```

Comment: No such luck (made the changes, same display happened). I am using Drupal 7 though, I'm going to guess that's the problem.